# How to remove classpath variables from WAS module

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, application-server

On our Dev box, our application module contains references to the `file:/apps/WebSphere61/systemApps/isclite.ear/` jar files and classpath entries.  On our Prod box, however, it only contains the jar file containing all of our required classes.  On Dev, this is causing a problem when using apache-commons-fileuploader as these classes are also references in the systemApps jar.  How can we remove the systemApps library references from our application module's classpath?

Websphere Application Server 6.1.0.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of spots where libraries are referenced.

I assume that you want test to match prod.

Start the admin console (on test).
There are libs defined on the Environment > Shared Libraries area and also in the Applications > Ent. Apps. > "my ear" > (additional properties) Libraries section.

See if it's defined in the  Env > Shared Libraries area and remove it.

Comment: I forget how we solved this issue, and I'm not with that company anymore.  Since you're the sold answer, and it looks logical enough--I'll give you the solution :)